# Remove space between book title and publisher in IEEEtranSN bibliography

Tags: bibliographies, natbib

I am using `natbib` and `bibtex` and the bibliography style `IEEEtranSN`. When using the `book` bibliography entry, there seems to be some extra space inserted between the title of the book and the publisher. Is there a way to remove this extra space?

In my document, I'm using the font `\usepackage{newtxtext}` and this is what is looks like:

[image]

**MWE**

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{report}
\usepackage[round]{natbib} 
\usepackage{filecontents}
\usepackage{newtxtext}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@book{examplebook,
  author = {Author, A.},
  year = {2017},
  title = {Title},
  publisher = {Publisher},
}
@article{examplearticle,
  author = {Author, B.},
  year = {2018},
  title = {Title},
  journal = {Journal of X},
}
\end{filecontents}

\begin{document}

\citet{examplebook} \citet{examplearticle}

\bibliographystyle{IEEEtranSN}
\bibliography{\jobname}

\end{document}
```

*UPDATED*

Some digging has revealed that this is the intended behaviour of this bibliography style. From [How to Use the IEEEtran BIBTEX Style](http://ijet.pl/ijet-files/Bibtex.pdf):

[image]

However, my question still remains. How can I remove this extra space? I don't *have* to use this exact bibliography style, so if there is an **identical** alternative style that doesn't include the extra space I would welcome that as well.

Comment: The extra space seems intentional. Do you have to use the style *and* change that space?

Comment: There are tons of `.bst` files out there. It all depends on your definition of similar, I guess.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to be intentional. Indeed in lines 232-234 of `IEEETranSN.bst` we find

> ```
> % This is the LaTeX spacer that is used when a larger than normal space
> % is called for (such as just before the address:publisher).
> FUNCTION {large.space} { "\hskip 1em plus 0.5em minus 0.4em\relax " }
> ```

If you must use `IEEETranSN.bst` *and* get rid of the space follow the steps below.

1. Locate `IEEEtranSN.bst` on your machine. You can do this by typing `kpsewhich IEEEtranSN.bst` into the command line/terminal. Alternatively, obtain a copy of the file from CTAN http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/IEEEtran/bibtex/IEEEtranSN.bst
2. Copy the file to a location where TeX can find it. The document directory will do fine. See also https://texfaq.org/FAQ-inst-wlcf
3. Rename the file to `IEEEtranSN-normspace.bst` (the license of `IEEEtranSN.bst` strongly encourages you to change the name if you modify the file)
4. Open the file and find

   ```
   FUNCTION {large.space} { "\hskip 1em plus 0.5em minus 0.4em\relax " }
   ```

   in line 234.

   Change that line to

   ```
   FUNCTION {large.space} { " " }
   ```
5. Add your name and date and explain the modification in the comments at the top of the file.
6. Use `\bibliographystyle{IEEEtranSN-normspace}` instead of `\bibliographystyle{IEEEtranSN}` in your document.

Comment: @Milo That is indeed one of the locations that would work. In fact that is what I meant by "The document directory will do fine."

Comment: And how do I replace the fullstop (.) to (,) after booktitle. Please tell the modification in .bst for that also.

Comment: @rudreshdwivedi I suggest you as a new question about that specific issue.